# Proper REST URL format

Tags: rest

My REST API format:

- http://myserver.com/rest/messages - get all messages
- http://myserver.com/rest/messages/5 - get message with id=5

How should the URL look when I want to get all messages owned by a user with id=1?

- http://myserver.com/rest/messages/user/1
- OR
- http://myserver.com/rest/usermessages/1 (no such entity UserMessage exists in the system)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a filter/search for messages. This is usually done by query parameters:

```
GET http://myserver.com/rest/messages?ownedBy=1
```

Since `/messages` is a collection resource from which you want a subcollection, you filter it.